# How to replace a file which ws opened using sys.stdout in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using sys.stdout method to print the logs for test run. Now I am having a test case which will run every hour and my goal is to replace the log file with the latest one everytime it runs. But using the following code, the log is getting accululated in the same file every hour. How to achieve this goal?

```
                                except Exception as e:
                                    json_data = json_payload_prop
                                    sys.stdout = open("mylog.log", "a")
                                    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
                                    traceback.print_tb(tb)
                                    tb_info = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
                                    filename, line, func, text = tb_info[-1]
                                    print('An error occurred on line {} in statement {}'.format(line, text),end='\r')
                                    print("Test failure due to assertion error", end='\r')
                                    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2),end='\r')
                                    print("**************************************************************************" ,end='\r')
                                    fail = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file with mode append:

```py
open("mylog.log", "a")
```

Change it to write, to overwrite the file:

```py
open("mylog.log", "w")
```